# ActionBarSherlock android-support-v4 jar checksum difference

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

Can someone explain why the android-support-v4.jar included with ActionBarSherlock has a different size (and, therefore, checksum) then the one added automatically by Android when setting up a new project? Are their customizations to the support code included with ActionBarSherlock? If not, is it safe to replace this jar with android-support-v13.jar since it already includes all of the code in android-support-v4.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android-support-v4.jar included in ActionBarSherlock is [5 months old](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock/libs). Since then Google has [released several new versions](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) of the support library. Since the two versions differ their checksums won't match.

It is safe to replace the version included in ABS with the version you're using in your main project.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the default `android-support-v4.jar` from android project and copy that jar from `ActionBarSherlock`  library project. or vice verse.   It is safe.

That will resolve the confict.

***Reason***

It would be the reason that our sdk copies the newer version of that jar into new project but `ActionBarSherlock` would have the older version of the same.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why their checksums don't match?

Comment: It would be the reason that our sdk copies the newer version of that jar but ActionBarSherlock would have the older version of the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more elegant fix than deleting and adding files!

You just need to :

Right Click the project App Free
Go To "Android Tools" > "Add Support Library"
Approve the permissions and let it update the library
Repeat this process for the project App Library
The Android Support Library will then be in sync (: